# Google's website translator and content loaded via AJAX

Tags: javascript, translation

I am using [Google's website translator](http://translate.google.com/translate_tools) on a website I am developing. In one section of the website I use AJAX to load new content into the page. I was hoping that there was a way to tell the Google translator to re-translate the loaded content (I could provide a DOM element that the content resides in).

I can't find any documentation which suggests how to do this and it appears that the [Google Translate API](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html) is becoming a paid service. Is it possible to use the Google translator in the way I require or do you need to use the paid service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call a function to re-translate the page in the same place you render the ajax content:

```
$.getScript("//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit");
```

Here's an example on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/patridge/NQ4uE/

Comment: Firstly thanks for the answer and sorry for the slow reply... And thank you for the demo which shows what I wanted to achieve. However, your code isn't doing what you describe. It only calls the $.getScript once on document.ready (rather than on each ajax response). But the effect is what I want. I'm not sure if the translate widget changed recently to support ajax content or if I wrongly assumed it didn't work but this made me investigate enough to find out translation can work on ajax content!